# Using router as remote door to gain access to LAN network

Tags: router, mac-address, network-access

What I want is that only certain devices get remote access to my network.
I want to achieve this by using MAC address.

Configuring this in my main router is not an option because it's too much work to add MAC addresses each time I personally want to connect something in my house.

So what I though, is it maybe possible:

Add a second router, switch off its DHCP. And use it as MAC address "GATE"?
Connect my server to that router, so if a device wants to connect its MAC address needs to be listed in my router. I can still connect personal devices to my main router and easy connect.

My story maybe sounds noob-ish, I am new to this.

Comment: What sort of devices are you wanting to connect to the network? If its remote workers for example, you could look at using a VPN to allow them to tunnel through the internet and appear on the LAN as if they were sitting in the office.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

IP packets only have layer-3 IP addresses, not MAC addresses. MAC addresses are layer-2 addresses, and they do not cross routers since routers strip off the layer-2 frame at each router hop.

You will not see the MAC addresses from any remote sites.